# How to install Eclipse Luna or later on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3

Some have asked the question before and there are various responses, however none directly answered the question and so here it is again.  Appreciate any pointer.

Comment: Some brief googling seems to be suggesting that the performance you could expect from later versions of Eclipse on a Pi might be best described as 'miserable'. The Pi's CPU and RAM availability are pretty poor relative to even a 10 year old desktop PC. That's probably reason enough for nobody to put the hours in to get it working. I think you might be on your own on this one, but I suppose if you put in a few days on it you might be able to compile it yourself.

Comment: Go to `eclipse.org`, then to the download page, download it, unzip or untar it, then run it.

Comment: @goobering I just did some trials and the Raspberry 3 is powerful enough for casual Java development (if you have all your files on a USB drive and not the SD-card)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Good effort! It would be great if you could put together an answer outlining your install procedure, and any caveats (USB stick, etc.).

Comment: @ott There is no official Eclipse distribution for the Raspberry.  This will not work.

Comment: @goobering I added a off-the-shelf USB-harddisk and followed the instructions on https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/msd.md carefully.  The "next" firmware update was necessary as of 2017-01-17.  My system now boots without the SD-card.

Answer (score 2):

Use sudo apt-get install eclipse. Make sure to remove openjdk.

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk*
```

DON'T FORGET THE ASTERISK IN THE COMMAND!

https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/install-oracle-java-8-debian-jessie-raspbian-jessie-via-ppa

Follow that article to install oracle java on raspbian. Done.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install eclipse` installs Eclipse 3.8, but the OP clearly asked how to install Eclipse Luna (4.4) or later.

Comment: I keep getting an error when launching eclipse about 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter'. Any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

I have used Eclipse on the Raspberry PI models 2 and 3 and found the performance to be quite good when doing Java development with pi4j when using Oracle's Java 8. It is a bit slow to load (15 seconds or so) and you will notice a slight delay the first time any new item (editor, builder, etc) is run (presumably class loading), but once up and running, it runs pretty smoothly.  When debugging I/O device drivers etc, having it run native on the PI is great.

WARNING!!!!!!! CAUTIONARY note on running Eclipse native on the PI.  If you use apt-get to install eclipse, it will also install Open JDK and set eclipse to use it.  Open JDK is extremely slow when compared with Oracle's JDK so be sure to install oracle Java and use it.

Comment: While this is great information, it does not really address the question about how to install Luna on the pi.

Comment: Sorry.  I added it because when installing eclipse on the PI, this issue can make or break its usability so I thought it was relevant to installing.  But as you said, it does not literally address the install procedure itself.

Answer (score -3):

Although it is a bit old I found an [article](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=20503) of someone who wanted the same. You could do it with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

So it is possible but I'd recommend to just run Eclipse on your desktop device or laptop and just transfer the built files or source code to your Raspberry Pi.

Comment: The thread you link is about someone *failing* to install Luna.  I'm don't know what the current eclipse available on Rasbpian is, but presumably the OP would not be asking about a specific version if it were up to date with that.

Comment: The current version of Eclipse with Raspbian is 3.8.1 which does not support Java 8 (otherwise it would be fine)